# Cannot wait on a transparent proxy in ThreadPool nonblocking wait

Tags: c#, synchronization, task-parallel-library, marshalling

**Can I somehow register nonblocking handler on marshalled signal in different app domain?**

I have a class that cannot be MarhsalByRef, yet I need to be able to call a method A on in in a different app domain D and then method B in the same app domain D.
This is could be easily solved by MarshalByRef - but I cannot use due to other code.

So I use a simple marshallable event and signal to the other app domain. I'd want to register a nonblocking handler in the other app domain - but it doesn't seem possible. I'm left with active wait?

Below is the repro:

```
    [Serializable]
    //this cannot be MarshalByRefObject
    public class AppDomainTest
    {
        private readonly ManualResetEvent _mrse = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public static void Test()
        {
            AppDomainTest ap = new AppDomainTest();
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ap.CreateDomainAndRun());
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            ap.CallIntoDomain();
        }

        public void CreateDomainAndRun()
        {
            var otherDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence);

            Task.Run(() => otherDomain.DoCallBack(RunInternal));
        }

        public void CallIntoDomain()
        {
            this._mrse.Set();
        }

        private void RunInternal()
        {
            //----------- HERE IS THE REPRO ---------------- //
            //This crashes
            //"Cannot wait on a transparent proxy"
            //ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(_mrse, CancellationCallBack, null,
            //    Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, true);

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                //This works just fine
                _mrse.WaitOne();
                CallIntoDomainInternal();
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).Wait();
        }

        private void CancellationCallBack(object state, bool timedOut)
        {
            CallIntoDomainInternal();
        }

        private void CallIntoDomainInternal()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"App domain: {AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName}");
        }
    }
```

Registering callback with ThreadPool throws 'Cannot wait on a transparent proxy'. Active wait in task works just fine.